# Cross between an edit distance algorithm and a phonetic algorithm

Tags: nlp

My aim is to find an edit distance algorithm which penalises transformations differently depending on the phonetic context.

Take the Levenshtein algorithm, for example; it penalises the same operation - like a character substitution - equally, regardless of character context.

However, it seems to me that all substitutions/insertions/deletions are not made equal. For example, in *some* contexts, the transformation `C->K` should **not** be as harshly penalised as `A->T`.

A phonetic algorithm, like [Double Metaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone), can help here. It maps both `kosmetik` and `cosmetic` to the same phonetic key, but it's aggressive and discards information. There's a clear difference between these two strings even though the phonetic key is the same.

Simply taking the Metaphone key and applying an edit distance algorithm is a poor choice for my goal.

Does a suitable method exist here? Or is the best option to manually fiddle with the internals of an edit distance algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations in the edit distance can have different weights that you can try to set manually. In Python, you can use e.g., [strsympy](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity) or [weighted-levenshtein](https://github.com/infoscout/weighted-levenshtein) package.

There is also [Learnable Edit Distance algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3192848_Learning_String_Edit_Distance) that allows learning the operation weights from data. I think it might be a good idea first to estimate the operation cost first manually and then fine-tune it with the learning algorithm.  Unfortunately, I am not aware of any reasonable implementation.

There is also a [CRF-based classifier](https://github.com/dirko/pyhacrf) that is based on the learnable edit distance. Based on training data, it estimates the probability of one string being a transcription of another one. This approach requires positive and negative training examples.